# piechart generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How to create a pie chart dynamically in mvc2 without using silverlight or any such tool.?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Google Chart Tools](http://goo.gl/nmAaf).